# In revel.Controller, How to get port set in app.conf

Tags: http, go, revel

Using revel framework (golang), how can I get port I set in app.conf?

```
// in app.conf
http.port=9090
```

And I have to use my server's port number in controllers (for example OAuth coding) such as

```
requestToken, url, err := TWITTER.GetRequestTokenAndUrl(
    "http://127.0.0.1:9090/Application/Authenticate",
)
```

I don't want to write port number by hard coding.
Using revel, is there any good way to get port number (or any other conf values) set in app.conf?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this documentation will be useful - http://robfig.github.io/revel/docs/godoc/config.html

For example

```
// Load app.conf
var err error
Config, err = LoadConfig("app.conf")
if err != nil || Config == nil {
    log.Fatalln("Failed to load app.conf:", err)
}
HttpPort = Config.IntDefault("http.port", 9000)
```

An another approach may be used instead direct loading (see **modules/db/app/db.go**)

```
import (
    "github.com/robfig/revel"
)

if option, found = revel.Config.String("option"); !found {
    revel.ERROR.Fatal("No option found.")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I found that but feeling a bit embarrassed.('cause it's too direct way, isn't it?) Anyway, that can provide me what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's too direct =) I've updated answer - if I understand correctly, `Config` is global variable for revel module.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

**In your file `app/init.go` you must retrieve config values within a custom-made function.**

**This custom made function must be registered in `func init()` with `revel.OnAppStart(MyFunc)`.**

---

If you attempt to retrieve config values directly from the `init()` func, you will recieve an error that looks something like this:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```